# Displaying inspection results, grouped per user selection

Tags: wpf, rubberduck, xaml

The Rubberduck 2.0 *Code Inspections* UI was recently redesigned (again!), this time featuring a `GroupingGrid` control (thanks @BrunoCosta!), and *what appears to be* a dynamic grouping:

[image]

**Resources**

The `UserControl`'s resources include two `CollectionViewSource` definitions, which determine the sorting and grouping rules for the user-selectable grouping styles.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Rubberduck.UI.CodeInspections.InspectionResultsControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:inspections="clr-namespace:Rubberduck.Inspections"
             xmlns:resx="clr-namespace:Rubberduck.UI"
             xmlns:codeInspections="clr-namespace:Rubberduck.UI.CodeInspections"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Rubberduck.UI.Controls"
             xmlns:componentModel="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
             ResxExtension.DefaultResxName="Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI" 
             Language="{UICulture}"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" 
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance codeInspections:InspectionResultsViewModel}">
<UserControl.Resources>

    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibility"/>

    <Style x:Key="LinkButton" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource ResourceKey={x:Type Button}}">
        <!-- irrelevant -->
    </Style>

    <codeInspections:InspectionSeverityImageSourceConverter x:Key="SeverityIconConverter" />
    <codeInspections:InspectionImageSourceConverter x:Key="InspectionIconConverter" />
    <codeInspections:InspectionTypeConverter x:Key="InspectionTypeConverter" />

    <Style x:Key="IconStyle" TargetType="Image">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="16" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="16" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4" />
    </Style>

    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ResultsByInspectionType" Source="{Binding Results}">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <componentModel:SortDescription PropertyName="Inspection.Name"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Inspection" Converter="{StaticResource InspectionTypeConverter}" />
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>

    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ResultsByModule" Source="{Binding Results}">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <componentModel:SortDescription PropertyName="QualifiedSelection.QualifiedName.ComponentName"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="QualifiedSelection.QualifiedName" />
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>

</UserControl.Resources>
```

**Content**

So, here's the actual control:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="64" />
        <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="48"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Background="#FFEEF5FD" />

    <ToolBar Grid.Row="0">

        <Button Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}">
            <Image Height="16" Source="../../Resources/arrow-circle-double.png" />
        </Button>

        <Separator />
        <Menu>
            <MenuItem VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                      Header="{Resx ResxName=Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI, Key=Fix}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.QuickFixes}">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Height="16" Source="../../Resources/tick.png" />
                </MenuItem.Icon>
                <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.QuickFixCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Menu, AncestorLevel=1}}" />
                        <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}" />
                        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Description}" />
                    </Style>
                </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>

        <Menu>
            <MenuItem Header="Grouping">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Height="16" Source="../../Resources/Microsoft/PNG/GroupBy_284_32.png" />
                </MenuItem.Icon>

                <MenuItem x:Name="GroupByInspectionType"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Header="By inspection type" IsChecked="True" 
                          IsCheckable="True" controls:MenuItemGroup.GroupName="GroupingStyle" />
                <MenuItem x:Name="GroupByModule" VerticalAlignment="Center" Header="By module" 
                          IsCheckable="True" controls:MenuItemGroup.GroupName="GroupingStyle" />
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>

        <Separator />

        <Button Command="{Binding CopyResultsCommand}">
            <Image Height="16" Source="../../Resources/document-copy.png" />
        </Button>

    </ToolBar>

    <controls:GroupingGrid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ResultsByInspectionTypeGrid"
                           ShowGroupingItemCount="True"
                           SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
                           ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResultsByInspectionType}}"
                           Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=GroupByInspectionType, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{Resx ResxName=Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI, Key=CodeInspectionResults_Type}">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="inspections:ICodeInspectionResult">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Inspection, Converter={StaticResource InspectionIconConverter}}" Height="16" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Resx ResxName=Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI, Key=CodeInspectionResults_Location}" Binding="{Binding QualifiedSelection.QualifiedName}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Resx ResxName=Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI, Key=CodeInspectionResults_Issue}" Binding="{Binding Description}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </controls:GroupingGrid>

    <controls:GroupingGrid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ResultsByModuleGrid"
                           ShowGroupingItemCount="True"
                           SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
                           ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResultsByModule}}"
                           Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=GroupByModule, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{Resx ResxName=Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI, Key=CodeInspectionResults_Type}">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="inspections:ICodeInspectionResult">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Inspection, Converter={StaticResource InspectionIconConverter}}" Height="16" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Resx ResxName=Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI, Key=CodeInspectionResults_Location}" Binding="{Binding QualifiedSelection.QualifiedName}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Resx ResxName=Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI, Key=CodeInspectionResults_Issue}" Binding="{Binding Description}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </controls:GroupingGrid>

    <resx:BusyIndicator Grid.Row="1" Width="36" Height="36" Visibility="{Binding IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}" />

    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="2" Height="5" ShowsPreview="True" Cursor="SizeNS" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

    <Border Grid.Row="3" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" BorderBrush="DimGray">

        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" MinHeight="48" Background="Gainsboro">

            <StackPanel Margin="4" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Image Style="{StaticResource IconStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                       Source="{Binding SelectedItem.Inspection.Severity, Converter={StaticResource SeverityIconConverter}}"/>
                <TextBlock Margin="4" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Inspection.Description}" FontWeight="Bold" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            </StackPanel>

            <TextBlock Margin="4" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Inspection.Meta}" FontSize="10" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            <TextBlock Margin="8" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.QualifiedSelection}" FontSize="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" />

            <WrapPanel>
                <Button Style="{StaticResource LinkButton}" Margin="4"
                        Visibility="{Binding CanExecuteQuickFixInModule, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}"
                        Command="{Binding QuickFixInModuleCommand}"
                        Content="{Resx ResxName=Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI, Key=QuickFix_ThisModule}" />
                <Button Style="{StaticResource LinkButton}" Margin="4"
                        Visibility="{Binding CanExecuteQuickFixInProject, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}"
                        Command="{Binding QuickFixInProjectCommand}"
                        Content="{Resx ResxName=Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI, Key=QuickFix_ThisProject}" />
                <Button Style="{StaticResource LinkButton}" Margin="4"
                        Visibility="{Binding CanDisableInspection, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}"
                        Command="{Binding DisableInspectionCommand}"
                        Content="{Resx ResxName=Rubberduck.UI.RubberduckUI, Key=DisableThisInspection}" />
            </WrapPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>

</Grid>
```

I'd like to bring your attention to this part:

> ```
> <controls:GroupingGrid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ResultsByModuleGrid"
>                        ShowGroupingItemCount="True"
>                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
>                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResultsByModule}}"
>                        Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=GroupByModule, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}">
> ```

And:

> ```
> <controls:GroupingGrid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ResultsByInspectionTypeGrid"
>                        ShowGroupingItemCount="True"
>                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
>                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResultsByInspectionType}}"
>                        Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=GroupByInspectionType, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}">
> ```

It completely reeks of a hack, but I haven't managed to get anything else to work. Is there any better way to do this? Copy-Pasta can't be the right way... *right?* ...Anything else smells in this markup?

I can provide the C# ViewModel and related classes if additional context is needed, but I wanted this post to be about the markup.

Comment: FWIW, for somebody who doesn't know [tag:wpf], this looks perfectly reasonable, nice code. I'm more concerned that further optimization attempts might be venturing into over-engineering-land, and risk increasing complexity rather than reducing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently toggling visibility of controls like that, is common practice in WPF; there's no way to toggle the `ItemsSource` in xaml, so what you have is pretty much as good as it gets.

Minor things stick out though:

> ```
> xmlns:resx="clr-namespace:Rubberduck.UI"
> ```

The only thing in that namespace is the `BusyIndicator` control, which would be better off in the `controls` namespace.

Probably an oversight, but every label is localized, except the ones in the "Grouping" menu, which are hard-coded:

> ```
> <MenuItem Header="Grouping">
> ```

The `x:Name` attributes on the `GroupingGrid` controls shouldn't be needed (a [quick search](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ResultsByModuleGrid) in the Rubberduck repository shows it's not referenced anywhere), get rid of them.